# Customize the action bar color background changing

Tags: android, customization, android-actionbar

I am trying to add and action bar to my app, and customize it.

i used onCreateOptionMenu() and Inflaters to add to my code.

but i don't know how to customize background and remove that package name which appears next to the logo so i can give more "Room" to my items to be displayed correctly.
can anybody help please?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to create a custom action bar in layout folder and use it with below code:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar(); //Applications action bar isntance
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.my_action_bar);
```

If you use this, you can directly use action bar view's content and do whatever you want.

Comment: Do i have to set a particular theme for the layout?

Comment: Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: since my action bar buttons are added as items with the Inflater way, do i have to add it as an item for R.layout.my_action_bar or just classic buttons with a set background.

Comment: @Hosni: It depends on your requirements. As per my view, just create a layout with custom attributes/views and display it for your application.Setting style is not mandatory for above code.

Comment: @Hosni: Check [link](http://www.android-dev-faq.com/2011/11/how-to-add-custom-layout-in-honeycomb.html) link for more info